# VB.NET: Readline from line until end

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to ask if there's a way to use "readline", that it reads from a certain line until the end of the file.
I need it because the user can save values from the program to a text file. Later he has a possibility to call the values back to the main program( ex. he wants to edit the values)

Everything works fine, but I have a multiline textbox, and if the user press ENTER, then after saving its immpossible to get the data in the right possition.
What I search, is a way to tell the program, to read from line 20 until the end of the file

My Text saving code

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Dim Saveb As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim myStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Saveb.Filter = "Text [*.txt*]|*.txt|All Files [*.*]|*.*"
    Saveb.CheckPathExists = True
    Saveb.CreatePrompt = False
    Saveb.FileName = "b" & (TextBox1.Text)
    Saveb.Title = "Speichern"
    Saveb.ShowDialog(Me)
    Try
        myStreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(Saveb.FileName)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox14.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox5.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox6.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(SrNr.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox4.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox2.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox5.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox6.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox7.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox8.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox9.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox10.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox1.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox14.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox11.Text & ".")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox3.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox12.Text & ".")

        myStreamWriter.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

And this is my reading code

```
 Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Static count As Integer
    count = count + 1
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim read As IO.StreamReader
        read = IO.File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox17.Text = read.ReadToEnd()
        largetext.Text = read.ReadToEnd()
        read.Close()
        Dim readLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = readLines(0)
        TextBox13.Text = readLines(1)
        TextBox14.Text = readLines(2)
        ComboBox5.Text = readLines(3)
        ComboBox6.Text = readLines(4)
        TextBox4.Text = readLines(5)
        SrNr.Text = readLines(6)
        ComboBox4.Text = readLines(7)
        ComboBox2.Text = readLines(8)
        TextBox5.Text = readLines(9)
        TextBox6.Text = readLines(10)
        TextBox7.Text = readLines(11)
        TextBox8.Text = readLines(12)
        TextBox9.Text = readLines(13)

        TextBox10.Text = readLines(14)
        TextBox2.Text = readLines(15)
        ComboBox1.Text = readLines(16)
        TextBox14.Text = readLines(17)
        TextBox11.Text = readLines(18)
        ComboBox3.Text = readLines(19)
        TextBox12.Text = readLines(20)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code gets into a hidden Textbox, from there it gets into the right place.
I know its not professional, but Im newbie.

Comment: It is not clear which of your many textboxes is the Multiline one. If it contains more than one line and it is in the middle of the output then you need a way to 'delimit' its content. In any case your approach to this task is weak. What if you need to add another field somewhere in between and you want to read back old files saved by a previous version of your program? (Not an uncommon scenario in my experience)

Comment: I will add the multi-textbox at the end, thats line 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting all the first textboxes and combos, you should recreate the [Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of the TextBox12

```
If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    Dim readLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    TextBox1.Text = readLines(0)
    .....
    TextBox12.Lines = readLines.Skip(20).ToArray
    ....

    TextBox17.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, readLines)
    largetext.Text = TextBox17.Text

End If
```

Setting the Text property of the textboxes requires that you rebuild a single string using String.Join as showed in the last lines

Notice that the call to ReadAllLines remove the need to call anything else using a StreamReader, you have already all of your lines in memory and you could work directly with that `readLines` array

Comment: Wow, thats really awesome and gives me a faster option, Thank you, thats the answer I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

**NB**. in your first sample (the writing) you do not close the file. Either use a `using` block or add a `myStreamWriter.Close()` in the `Finally` block of the `Try`.

You are already reading all the lines in the file, so you already have the data in an array, slicing the array is easy enough with a little LINQ

```
dim remainingLines = readLines.Skip(20).ToArray()
```

Comment: I added now a line that closes the file.

Comment: should I now add at the end like

textbox12.text = remaningLines.toString

??

Comment: I get 
system.string()

Comment: Use `String.Join` to convert array of strings into single string.